# Problem with PostgreSQL function parameter of type "name"

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I'm writing some PostgreSQL functions to compile a list of search terms for records in a table called `name`. Since the search terms come from multiple columns on the `name` table and from multiple columns on other tables, a simple generated column isn't sufficient.

Here's a simplified version of the function.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION compile_name_search_terms(n name) RETURNS text AS $$
BEGIN
  return n.id || ' ' ||
    COALESCE(n.full_name, '') || ' ' ||
    COALESCE(n.phone, '') || ' ' || 
    regexp_replace(COALESCE(n.phone, ''), '[\(\)-]', '', 'g');
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Attempting to execute

```sql
SELECT id, compile_name_search_terms(t) FROM name AS t;
```

throws error

```
ERROR:  function compile_name_search_terms(public.name) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT id, compile_name_search_terms(t) FROM name AS t;
                   ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 12
```

I have working functions for other tables `customer`, `vendor`, etc. but cannot figure out the syntax for the `name` table. I suspect the problem stems from the fact that the table name is a [non-reserved keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

I don't have the liberty to rename the `name` table as this is in production.

What syntax do I need to make this work?

Comment: WOW! of all the things I tried, why didn't I think of that? That works. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built-in data type called name which (being located in `pg_catalog`)  has a higher precedence than your table's type.

So the parameter type is actually `pg_catalog.name`.

To avoid the ambiguity you need to declare the parameter as a full qualified name: `public.name`